# WCF Data Services: request by multiple parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to generate a request to my WCF service.
I need to query WCF by datetime parameter OR by Ids.

I mean in the final result I want to get the url like
myservice.svc/MyObjects()?$filter=CreateDate ge datetime'datecomeshere' or Id eq 3 or Id eq 45 or Id eq 112

The problem is that I have a collection of ids on client side and one date variable.
So how can I generate this kind of request to WCF?

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
 var localEntityIds = DbConnection.ObjectContextConnection.GetEntitiesByDate<T>(DateToReplicate).Select(x => x.Id);
            if (DateToReplicate > DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                expQuery =
                    Service.CreateQuery<T>(SetName).Where(
                        x => x.ReplicaInfo.CreateDate >= DateToReplicate ||
                            x.ReplicaInfo.ModifyDate >= DateToReplicate || localEntityIds.Where(y=>y ==x.Id).Any()) as DataServiceQuery<T>;
            }
```

This code throws an exception that max protocol version should be not less than 3.0 and  Any method is not supported. 
But I have version 3.0

```
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
```

I've also tryed to solve this issue implementing this code, but wcf return nothing in this case:

```
     var localentities = DbConnection.ObjectContextConnection.GetEntitiesByDate<T>(DateToReplicate).Select(x => x.Id);
            if (DateToReplicate > DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                expQuery =
                    Service.CreateQuery<T>(SetName).Where(
                        x => x.ReplicaInfo.CreateDate >= DateToReplicate ||
                            x.ReplicaInfo.ModifyDate >= DateToReplicate) as DataServiceQuery<T>;
            }

            foreach (var localentity in localentities)
            {
                expQuery = expQuery.AddQueryOption("or", string.Format("Id eq guid'{0}'", localentity));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build whole where condition as a string and use `AddQueryOption("$filter", yourBuiltQueryString)`. As I know you cannot add only part of condition - name of added query option must start with `$` which is only defined set of operators. Because of that you cannot use `Where` condition in your query - whole condition must be added by `AddQueryOption` method call to build correct `or` sequence.

In case of `Any` make sure that you are using correct CTP (btw. CTP is not production ready release). It was added in [June 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-wcf-data-services-june-2011-ctp-for-net4-amp-sl4.aspx) and you must use that library on both server and client.